# Android Google Analytics API v4 Real Time

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have setup everthing in application for using google analytics V4 and I can see "Screens, Active Users,New Users and Top Device Models" but I don't see "Real-Time" data or active users on app.

global_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXX-X</string>
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>
<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>
<screenName name="com.sounds.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>
</resources>
```

app_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXX-X</string>
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
<string name="ga_appName">soundsapp</string>
<string name="ga_appVersion">3.4</string>
<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
<item name="ga_dispatchPeriod" format="integer" type="integer">120</item>
<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">90</string>
<bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>
<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">10</integer>
<string name="com.sounds.MainActivity">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
```

Trackers.java

```
public class Trackers extends Application {

 private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXX-X";
 public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;
 public enum TrackerName {
     APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
     GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
     ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
 }

 public HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

 public Trackers() {
     super();
 }

 public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
     if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
         GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
         Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID): (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker): analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
         mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

     }
     return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
   }
 }
```

Activity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
Tracker t = ((Trackers)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName("HomePage");    
    .....
 @Override
  protected void onStart() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  super.onStart();
  GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
  //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions etc.  
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStop();
  //Stop the analytics tracking
  GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
  }
```

Comment: I have the same problem.  I do see data the day after in the overview page but no  "Real-time" data. I'll let you know if I find something

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out to be a daylight saving time bug. Check the timezone in your analytics account. If it's not the correct current timezone in your area (you can use [this site](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/) to check the time in that timezone), change the timezone to another area which does have your correct timezone. Don't forget to change it back after they do move the clock in your country.